# Why do I still see the "beta" CSS?

Tags: support, status-completed, design

> This post refers to the white-on-black, blackboard design initially proposed in [Design for Physics-SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/447/design-for-physics-se). This design was withdrawn and (after a spell back in site-beta design) replaced with the current one, which first appeared in [New Site Design](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/new-site-design).

Why do I still see the "beta" [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS)?

I'm not seeing the styling that would indicate that this site is out of beta, I've tried hard refreshes, and using browsers that I've never used before.

Was the design actually launched, or not?

Comment: [The design](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/447/design-for-physics-se) was temporarily launched but due to [usability objections by many of us](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/479/can-we-please-change-the-design-to-black-on-white):
_[Based on extensive meta feedback, site design is withdrawn indefinitely. -- Jeff Atwood♦](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/479/can-we-please-change-the-design-to-black-on-white/488#488)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design was launched and withdrawn based on community feedback. Browse the [design](/questions/tagged/design) tag for more.

Comment: Also worth noticing that the word "beta" doesn't appear in our logo (up where it says "Physics" or "Physics meta"), as it would for a beta site.

Comment: ...and this presumably means that we'll get another go when Jin gets (a) a [round tuit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/round_tuit) and (b) another inspiration.