# New Site Design

Tags: discussion, design

I'd like to present the community with a new final site design I've been working on. The goal is to keep the site clean and minimalistic, but at the same time give our physics site a unique branding. I gave the layout some extra spacing and line height for readability, also the colors have been tested for color blindness. I apologize for the first design, I learned my lesson the [hard way](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/463/new-design-launched)!

<sub>Below are the mockups, please click on the images to see full resolution versions.</sub>

**Home Page**

[image: Physics Homepage]

**Question Page**

[image: Physics Question page]

If the community approves this design, I'll be converting it to CSS and hopefully launch the design next week. Also, I'll be creating top user swag (T-Shirt and stickers) and moderator cards soon. Below is a mockup of the shirt.

[image: Physics T-Shirt]

Please let me know what you think!

Comment: As a quick first impression, it looks fantastic! Thanks a lot, Jin!

Comment: I want a T-shirt :-) !

Comment: Stickerssssss~!

Comment: Oh well - nowhere near enough rep to qualify for a T-shirt :(

Comment: Looks great, but could do with having a vote on alternatives for the Higgs Mexican hat graphic which might look too basic to some.

Comment: Awesome job! And thanks for giving us a second shot! (Also, I'd want that T-shirt...)

Comment: @Jin [Can we have a candle on our logo?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1068/can-we-have-a-candle-on-our-logo)

Answer (score 6):

As far as I'm concerned, the contrast of the main page is far to low. Why not make the titles of the question a little darker?

Comment: Another problem I have with the “accept“ button is that it looks like it is not activated since the saturation is so low.

Comment: @queueoverflow: Well yeah, also I don't know if the tags on the main site work if one clicks them. Btw. the contrast now seems to be better then when I made that comment two weeks ago.

Answer (score 5):

I've been thinking over this today, and yep, I still like it ;-) It reminds me that [the first time through](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304/what-should-our-site-look-like), there were a lot of suggestions about cute ways to work physics concepts and notation into the design, but I think we'll be better off with a design like this that just gets out of the way, so to speak.

Personally I'd be quite happy with the exact design you've posted screenshots of, but I do have a few speculative thoughts:

- The page footer seems insufficiently distinguished from the rest of the page. Maybe it's just me, but I think it would be nice to have some visual indication that the main content of the page has ended and that you're now looking at a generic footer. What about putting the same grid and gradient you use in the header, or perhaps a faded version of it, as a background for the footer?
- Same goes for the right sidebar; it seems insufficiently distinguished from the main content of the page, though more so on the question list than the individual question page. Of course I'm not suggesting using the grid/gradient background for the sidebar, but perhaps there's something subtle that could be done there, like giving it a faint left border, or a slightly off-white background color, or fading the text, or whatever tricks you have up your sleeve for this sort of thing ;-)
- Regarding the vertical alignment of the text of the site name and the page tabs on the right (questions, tags, etc.): when I look at it closely I do see that the baselines are aligned, but if I'm not focusing on that alignment specifically, it qualitatively seems just a little off. I'm wondering what it would look like if the names of those tabs were raised up by just a couple of pixels.
- The tags also seem to blend into the background a bit. What would you think about putting a thin border of a marginally darker shade on the left side of each tag?

Also, do we get a custom image on the 404 page? That's one place I think we could get away with having some cute physics joke.

Comment: I can certainly do something with the footer, I think a faded gird may be good. as for the side bar, I think a thin line works. We use that treatment on our [UX site](http://ux.stackexchange.com/). for the alignment, I'll be sure to tweak that and the tag styling in the actual CSS implementation. I don't have any ideas for 404/captcha/error page images, maybe it's a good idea to start a new post to gather some ideas?

Comment: There were a few ideas for a 404 page proposed on the original design thread, but it certainly wouldn't hurt to take another crack at it. I posted [a question for it](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/ideas-for-404-error-captcha-pages-take-2) and we'll see what ideas come up.

Comment: I love the redesign.  It is very clean and visually appealing.  I have one fairly subtle point: shouldn't the Feynman diagram behind "Physics" be rotated 90 degrees?  To connote that we are meeting in one place to exchange information?

Comment: Ahh, sneaky @Jen ;-) There's an arrow below it indicating that time increases to the right, though.

Answer (score 4):

Elegant and visually pleasing, but as David notes it "gets out of the way" -- absolutely perfect for the site. On the other hand could we restart the search for a proper logo? I actually like the mexican hat favicon, but for the main image it's just a bit... lacking. Maybe it's just me.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the meta color scheme is better and I'd rather see that as the main site design.  Then it would be about perfect.

Just my 2 cents!  Good job getting this done.  Any design is better than the standard one.

Comment: Yes, the meta scheme struck me as having a more subtle elegance about it. I'd also prefer this for the main page, but with the gold text replaced by either black, some shade of grey, or a subtle colour that blends with the neutral text, rather than screaming out for attention as in the case of the current gold colour.

Comment: It is a common convention across the network that meta sites' color schemes are "grayed-out" versions of their main sites' color schemes. If we put the meta site scheme on the main site, I'm not sure what could be done to make it more gray ;-) (Also, personally I do just prefer the main site color scheme, but that's me)

Comment: It's taken some time, but it has grown on me - both color schemes.

Answer (score 2):

Good job! Overall I love the clean look of the new design, the color scheme, all of it.  The only criticism I have is that the color on meta seem to have lower contrast now, specifically the light brown text. This makes it a little difficult (though not impossible!) for older eyes like mine to view the site with comfort.

Comment: Mark are you referring to the link color on Meta?

Comment: oh, you're right! It is just the color on Meta. the main site colors are fine.

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit confused. At present I see a changed current format already. In this one my only comment is that the yellow/gold used for links and names  is too faint for my laptop screen . The faded feeling does not attract clicking.

The mock up gives better contrast to the yellow and is fine as it uses little yellow/gold (none?).

Comment: Are you looking at meta or the main site?

Comment: the main site.But today it is only the meta side line that is gold, and that is fine. If I change the angle of the lap top screen it gets better contrast.