# New New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design

The "new new design" just went live, thanks for the [feedback](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/new-site-design)!.

If you see any CSS glitches, **please start a new post**, and tag it with "Design" and "Bug" so I can track them easily.

For now I'm using generic 404 and error images. I plan to make final ones based off [your ideas](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/ideas-for-404-error-captcha-pages-take-2). So please feel free to submit!

Once again, congrats!

Comment: Great job, thanks!

Comment: Looks good :-) but... is something going on with the background of the footer? When the design first launched I thought I saw a colored background down there but now it just looks white.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky it seems fine to me. Try hard refreshing the page to see if the problem persists. Occasionally we get some CDN connection problem where static content(images, css etc) fail to load.

Comment: No luck, I'm still seeing the white footer, even after multiple hard refreshes and switching browsers..

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky are you able to see http://cdn.sstatic.net/physicsmeta/img/bg-grid.png ? it's a light gray png. also, what OS and browser are you using?

Comment: ahh, I think I figured it out: I had my monitor contrast turned all the way up, so that light gray was visually indistinguishable from white. I dialed down the contrast and now I can see the different background shade. It just seemed strange because I thought I remembered seeing a darker background earlier. This is in Chromium 17 and Firefox 9, both on Gentoo Linux, if it still matters.

Comment: I can't log in using IE 8 on the main physics stack exchange site.

Comment: On at least two of my computers the "accept answer" color change is so slight as to be almost or entirely undetectable to me. (or imperceptible?)   I vote for more distinctive colors throughout the design.